# Property of Function not increasing properly?

Tags: javascript, post-increment

I am practicing some various JavaScript techniques, namely function properties.  Here is something that has me scratching my head a little.

```
//property of the q0 function
q0.unique = 0;


function q0() {

return q0.unique++;

}

console.log(q0()); //returns 0 
console.log(q0()); //returns 1
console.log(q0()); //returns 2
console.log(q0()); //returns 3
```

Shouldn't the first call to the function return 1?  Why is it returning 0?  q0.unique is already set to 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be true if your code was:

```
function q0() {

return ++q0.unique;

}
```

The suffixed `++` returns the current value *then* increments. With a prefixed `++` it's the other way around.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  A pre besides a post.

Answer (score 2):

The postfix increment operator returns the value before the increment.

```
var a = 0;
var b = a++;
// now a==1 and b==0
```

The best way to recall it is to read `a++` as `give the value and then increment`.

If you want to return the value after the increment, use

```
return ++q0.unique;
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing pre- and post-incrementation. Given:

```
var unique = 0;
```

`var x = unique++` will assign *current* value of `unique` (`0`) while `var x = ++unique` will assign value of `unique` after incrementation (`1`). In both cases the value of `unique` is `1` after all.

What you want is:

```
function q0() {
  return ++q0.unique;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two increment operators:

```
var++ // increment  the variable ---after--- the operation.  
++var // increment  the variable ---before-- the operation.
```

Example:

```
var x = 0;

alert(x++) // 0
alert(x)   // 1
alert(++x) // 2
```